# Bootstrap tab ajax load content when page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need help about loading tab content  when page is loaded. My example work good but default tab load content only when i click on him. That content is not loaded automatically when page is loaded is empty.

**Check:**
[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoWw/77dyfbwd/)

Like on example u will see you

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
   <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843293/" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
   <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843301/" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
   <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843306/" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">
   </div>
</div>
```

**And js:**

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place this at the very end of your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tabajax"]:first').click();
});
```

Comment: Can confirm this still works very well and is still the cleanest and easiest way of preparing an ajax tab on load. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

that's it worked here is the complete js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
                targ = $this.attr('data-target');

                $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
                $(targ).html(data);
                });

                $('[data-toggle="tab"]:eq(0)').trigger('click');

                $this.tab('show');
                return false;
            });


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="tab"]:first').click();
            });


       </script>
```

Thanks a lot